# How do I condition routes with the same URL to call different components depending on whether a feature is on or not?

Tags: reactjs, routes, conditional-statements

I have 2 different route scenarios that occur with the same URL but call different components.

```
<Route path={generatePaths('success')}>{decorateWithLayout(SuccessComponentOne)}</Route>
<Route path={generatePaths('success')}>{decorateWithLayout(SuccessComponentTwo)}</Route>
```

When `FeatureFlag` is on, we expect to be directed to the first one, when `FeatureFlag` is off we get the second one.

I'm not sure how to do the conditional. Shall I do it in the roots or create a new component that will replace SuccessComponentOne and SuccessComponentTwo that will contain the login for the conditional in there?

Answer (score 0):

If it was me I would make a ternary operator.

```js
let flag = true;

const successComponent = flag ? < Component1 / > : < Component2 / > ;

<Route path={generatePaths('success')}>{decorateWithLayout(successComponent)}</Route>
```